How to make a question in this case?
If we look at the sentence in Present Perfect tense, then it's obvious how to form question here:

Usual form: You have done tasks.

Question: What tasks have you done?


But if we look at this one, when "done" is just a Past Participle adjective, not a part of Present Perfect tense, then I don't know for sure how I can make a question here, but I suppose it should be like this:

Usual form: You have tasks done.

Question: What tasks do you have done?


For some reason a grammar check program says me that it's wrong and tries to change it to "What tasks have you done?" instead of "What tasks do you have done?". How should it be actually?

You have tasks done is not idiomatic English, so it's not surprising that your grammar checker doesn't like your question. Do you mean that someone has a list of tasks that they have completed?

The words "do" and "done" are somewhat idiomatic and unusual, compared to more specific verbs like "communicate", "prepare", "influence", and thousands of others. Almost any other! If you choose a verb like "analyze", do you understand completely how to use the Present Perfect and the Participle? That should be the first step....
